# Reset interval in JS image sideshow

Tags: javascript

How can I reset interval onclick in JavaScript.  I have the following tutorial and everything works bt I can get the sideshow to re-start on click.

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = ["_images/overlook.jpg","_images/winery_sign.jpg","_images/lunch.jpg",
             _images/bigSur.jpg","_images/flag_photo.jpg","_images/mission_look.jpg"];
                 var imageIndex = 0;


function changeImage (){
    myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray [imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;

if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
    imageIndex = 0;
}
 }

 var intervalHandler = setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
myImage.onclick = function (){
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
}

**// The code below doesn’t work**

 var intervalReset = clearInterval;
myImage.onclick = function (){
    setInterval(intervalReset);
};
```

Comment: Can someone please help me with the above I have tried all the possiblities.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `onclick` twice, that **replaces** the handler, so only the later definition will count. Use `addEventListener` instead:

```
myImage.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //first set of stuff
});

myImage.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //more stuff
});
```

And only your first function makes sense. You might want to also reset `imageIndex` to 0.

So all-in-all, your code should look something like:

```
var intervalHandler = setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
myImage.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
    imageIndex = 0;
    intervalHandler = setInterval(changeImage, 5000); //restart again
});
```

Comment: hello do i also need to add this 
 var intervalReset = clearInterval;

Comment: @user1960982 Nope. Don't do that `intervalReset = clearInterval` at all. Just the above + the `var intervalHandler = setInterval(changeImage, 5000);` definition.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback, I couldn't get it to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval returns an interval ID which you use to clear the interval:

```
var intervalDuration = 5000;
myImage.onclick = function (){
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
    // Assumes intervalDuration is defined
    intervalHandler = setInterval(changeImage, intervalDuration);
};
```

Comment: Hello Konstaintin I try the code you provided and it dodnt work, Thanks for you help anyway. I am a beginner to JS and webdesign

Comment: Hi Konstin it still not working for some reason on my script.

Comment: Hello Konstin, Please can you look at the code again because it not working.